# Delta method for third moment

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, moments, delta-method

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ is a sample from a population with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and third central moment of $\mu_3$. I want to justify that:
$$E[\left( h(\bar{X})-E(h(\bar{X}))\right)^3]=\frac{1}{n^2}[h'(\mu)]^3\mu_3+\frac{3}{n^2}h''(\mu)[h'(\mu)]^2\sigma^4+O(n^{-3})$$

I found a lemma as if $E|X_1|^j<\infty,j>2$ then there are constants $C_j>0$ and $D_j>0$ such that $$|E(\bar{X}-\mu)^j|\leq D_jE|X_1|^jn^{-(j+1)/2},\quad j\text{ is odd}$$

Update:
I found out that doing Taylor series of $h(\bar{X})$ at $h(\mu)$ to the first order, and then considering the 3rd power of $h(\bar{X})-h(\mu)$ should work but I don't know how to actually implement this.

Any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: Why is $h$ not defined?